# Center an button with respect to an image CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I need a page where centered in the middle there is an image and inside of it there is button. What I am not able to achieve is to force the button to remain in the same position when the browser window is re-sized. 
This is the page:
http://jsfiddle.net/afg5wrLz/

The HTML code:

```
<div id="MyImage">
    <img id="theImage" src="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg">
    <button id="myButton">Start Here</button>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#MyImage{
    position: relative;
}

#theImage{
   position: relative;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-top: 20px;
   display: block;    
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   max-width: 400px;
}
#myButton{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
}
```

Now if you re-size the window you will see the problem; the left coordinate of the button is related to the window and not to the image so when you re-size the window the button moves while I want it to remain in the same position in the image.
To have a better idea of what I need head to http://www.whatsapp.com/ and look at the behavior of the Download WhatsApp button or the text "Simple. Personal ..." if you re-size the window you will see they remain in the same position with respect to their background image which remains centered in the screen as the width changes. 
I would like to know what I need to change in my code to achieve that result

Comment: You want start here button in the middle of the image and the image centered on the page or centered inside #myImage div ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a centered image with a button inside following the image http://jsfiddle.net/afg5wrLz/2/

The HTML

```
<div id="MyImage">
    <img id="theImage" src="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg" />
    <button id="myButton">Start Here</button>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#MyImage {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
}
#theImage {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#myButton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Center a button on other div

```
position: absolute;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
margin-right: -50%;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

this structure works . check if this is acceptable

the html

```
    <div id="MyImage">
        <img id="theImage" src="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg" />
        <button id="myButton">Start Here</button>
    </div>
```

and the corresponding css

```
#MyImage {
    position: relative;
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto; /*this will center your button and image as mentioned by @BojanPetkovski in the comment*/
}
#theImage {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 400px;
}
#myButton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Center tag is deprecated :) This feature has been removed from the Web. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign a fixed `width` to your `#MyImage` div in order to replicate what you see on the Whatsapp website. Here's a **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/afg5wrLz/1/)** which I've created for you by assigning a `width` of `1000px` to the `#MyImage` div.

CSS:

```
#MyImage{
    width: 1000px;
}
```

You can reduce the width of the result's window and see that the button stay in its place.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the start button to be center of the image then , check this code

```
       <div id="MyImage">

         <img id="theImage" src="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize   /PIA17011_ip.jpg">
        <button id="myButton">Start Here</button>

        </div>

        #MyImage{
             position: absolute;   
               }

      #theImage{
            position: relative;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 0px;
            display: block;    
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            max-width: 400px;
             }

          #myButton{
               position: absolute;
               left:150px;
               z-index:1;
               top:200px;
              }
```